# AWS 3-Tier Architecture Query

Tags: amazon-web-services, rest, architecture, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, devops

Need some serious help here, thanks a lot in advance !

*I put out a similar question the other day, didn't get the answer I was looking for. So refactored the entire question*

I need to deploy a scalable 3 tier web application on AWS and I am having some doubts/trouble understanding the best practice to design the architecture.

NOTE: As per my understanding, all the backend requests are requested through the browser, after the Frontend server serves html/css/js to the user.

This is the solution I found online :

[image]

> **Question**

- Doesn't it kill all the logic that 'all the requests to the backend api is made through the client's web browser (since the frontend servers serve html/js code to the user's browser)'? WHICH MEANS, the request should go from the browser --> externalLoadbalancer --> backend API
- Considering this, how would the routing in this work? Because, we cannot use frontend for routing, can we?

---

Right solution IMO (***But it doesn't provide restriction to the backend API from the external world***):

[image]

*This definitely does not break any logic/concept but gives access to the world to access the backend api like* ***<domain_name/api>***

I am stuck with this design for days and I need to take the web app in production. I would REALLY APPRECIATE the help.

Comment: What is the application server running? What technologies is used on the Frontend? Is this only exposing an api gateway, or an entire monolith web app?

Comment: Frontend: React & Backend: Node.
The backend exposes API endpoints. Which I don't want the clients to access using <domain>/api

Comment: "we cannot use frontend for routing" ... If your frontend is an apache server, it can. If your frontend only hosts static files, use AWS S3 like proposed by Rodrigo M

Answer (score 3):

I think you should consider using the AWS API Gateway for access to private EC2 endpoints, and run react from S3 and CloudFront. I don't see those services called out in your architecture.

Here is a description of how the API Gateway supports private EC2 backends.

> At re:Invent 2017, we announced endpoint integrations inside a private VPC. With this capability, you can now have your backend running on EC2 be private inside your VPC without the need for a publicly accessible IP address or load balancer.

See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-amazon-api-gateway-private-endpoints/

See also https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/

Unless you need React rendering on the server, you can just run it as a static website from S3, and call all your application functions from the API Gateway. This is a common way to architect React apps on AWS.